# AWS email receiving WITHOUT SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

What would be the easiest way to receive emails and push them straight to SNS?

AWS SES is not an option because [email receiving](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/regions.html#region-receive-email) is not supported in my region and using other regions is against gov regulations for my case.

Hoping there's a better option than a self-managed mail server on EC2.

Comment: Can you receive emails on a 3rd-party system (eg Gmail)? You could then write something that calls the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides).

Comment: It has to be a specific domain for me. I have full control over the domain, have hosted zone setup in Route 53, just need to point the MX record at something that's in my region. Which us-east-1 isn't.

Comment: The MX record can point to any SMTP server on the Internet, hence my suggestion for Gmail. You could point to any email provider.

Comment: SMTP? Due to highly regulated nature of the client it has to be either a certified and PSAF-ed partner, like AWS, or something own and self managed, unfortunately. Won't be bringing a third provider for sure. Looks like postfix on EC2 it will be, unless AWS will live up to promises to bring SES to feature parity in our region really, really soon.

Comment: Perhaps [Amazon WorkMail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/userguide/what_is.html)? It is designed to be like Exchange, but it should serve your purpose of having a mail system. However, I don't think it would have any Amazon SNS integration.

Comment: That could have been an option! But funny enough, WorkMail is also only available in the same three regions as SES email receiving. A bit pricey too, $4 per user, would get expensive quick at our scale.